# Closed form for $F(n) = \sum_{i=1}^k F(n-i)$

Tags: summation, asymptotics, fibonacci-numbers

If we have $F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)$ and $F(0) = 0$ and $F(1) =1$ then we get the [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).  A closed form solution is:

$$
F_n = \left[\frac{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{5}}\right)^n}{\sqrt{5}}\right]
,$$

where $[]$ rounds to the nearest integer.

What do we get as a closed form solution for $F(n) = \sum_{i=1}^3 F(n-i)$ with $F(0) = 1, F(1) = 2, F(2) = 4$?

> In general, if we set $F(i) = a_i$ for $i \in
>  \{0,\dots,k-1\}$, $a_i \geq 0$ and constant $k >1$, what does the closed
>   form solution for $F(n) = \sum_{i=1}^k F(n-i)$ look like for large $n$?

Comment: Hint: Generating functions.

Comment: For every $k\geqslant1$ and every nonnegative $(a_i)$ (not all zero), $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{F(n)}{\rho_k^n}=c$$ where $c$ is positive and finite and depends on $(a_i)$, and $\rho_k$ is the largest real root of the polynomial $$x^k=x^{k-1}+\cdots+x+1$$ Hence $\rho_k$ is independent on $(a_i)$. Exact values of the $\rho_k$ for $k\geqslant5$ are not available but one can show that the sequence $(\rho_k)$ is increasing with $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\rho_k=2$$ Already for $k=4$, $$\rho_4\approx1.92756$$

Comment: @Did Thank you. Is it possible to get bounds for $\rho_k$ for $k>4$?

Comment: For every $k$, $\rho_k<2$. More precisely, $$\rho_k^k=\frac1{2-\rho_k}$$ hence $$\frac1{2-\rho_k}<2^k$$ which implies $$\rho_k<2-\frac1{2^k}$$ Furthermore, roughly speaking, this upper bound is actually the exact behaviour since one can show that $$\rho_k=2-\frac1{2^k}+O\left(\frac{k}{2^{2k}}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

*Example:*

$F(n)=F(n-1)+F(n-2)\enspace $ with given $\enspace F(0)\enspace $ and $\enspace F(1)$

$x^n=x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}\enspace$ means $\enspace x^2=x^1+x^0\enspace$ => $\enspace x\in\{x_1,x_2\}$

$F(n):=ax_1^n+bx_2^n$

Linear Equation System:   $\enspace ax_1^0+bx_2^0=F(0) \enspace $   and  $\enspace ax_1^1+bx_2^1=F(1)$

It follows $\,a\,$ and $\,b\,$ and therefore $\,F(n)$ .

*Note:* Now you know how to solve for the general $k\,$ (above: $\,k=2$) .

Comment: Thank you. So it seems impossible to solve for large $k$. Is it possible to get asymptotics for large $n$? It seems that you get closer and closer to $2^n$ as $k$ increases.

Comment: You have to check what the solutions are for $x^k=x^{k-1}+...+1$ . I don't know the asymptotic for $F$ (depending on the initial values). Maybe to create the generating function can help (I haven't tested). --- For $k$ odd we have one real and $k-1$ complex solutions, for $k$ even we have two real and $k-2$ complex solutions. The *exact* solution is $a_1 x_1^n + ... + a_k x_k^n$ and the coefficients $a_j$ can be solved by the linear equation system (which becomes unpleasant with large $k$) .

Comment: I have checked the solutions $x$ for some $k$ and indeed $F(n)$ is close to $(\max \Re(x_j))^n$ and therefore becomes close to $2^n$ . We know $2^n-1=2^{n-1}+...+2^0$ which makes this understandable.

Answer (score 0):

The solution has an increasing algebraic difficulty because a closed form is linked to the roots of an equation of degree $n$ just as in Fibonacci sequence you must solve $x^2-x-1=0$ for the your question $F(n) = \sum_{i=1}^3 F(n-i)$ you need to solve $ z^3-z^2-z-1=0$. Two roots are complex numbers and the general solution is quite ugly

For $n>4$, as you know,  in general there is no way to find roots by radicals  but the aspect is always similar to Fibonacci closed form. Roots of polynomial equations raised to $n$ and added together

An approximated form which works great is

$f(n)\approx -(0.0687258\, -0.123522 i) (-0.419643+0.606291 i)^n+(-0.0687258-0.123522 i) (-0.419643-0.606291 i)^n+1.13745\cdot 1.83929^n$

which gives the first terms

$1,\;2,\;4,\;7,\;13,\;24,\;44,\;81,\;149,\;274,\;504,\;927,\;1705,\;3136,\;5768,\;10609,\;19513,\;35890,\;66012,\;121415,\;223317,\ldots$

Comment: Thank you. So it seems impossible to solve for large $k$. Is it possible to get asymptotics for large $n$? It seems that you get closer and closer to $2^n$ as $k$ increases.

Comment: It depends on the initial values. For instance the following recurrence $f(n+4)=f(n+1)+f(n+2)+f(n+3)+f(n),f(0)=1,f(1)=2,f(2)=4,f(3)=8$ has values $1,\;2,\;4,\;8,\;15,\;29,\;56,\;108,\;208,\;401,\;773,\;1490,\;2872,\;5536,\;10671,\;20569,\;39648\ldots$ only because I gave $1,\;2,\;4,\;8$ as initial values. Otherwise I get $1,\;1,\;1,\;1,\;4,\;7,\;13,\;25,\;49,\;94,\;181,\;349,\;673,\;1297,\;2500,\;4819,\;9289,\;\ldots$